# Generate Buttons with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to create a certain number of 'buttons' based on the number of images with jQuery?

example:

```
<ul class="gallery">
    <li><img src="example-one.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="example-two.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="example-three.png" /></li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to create three nav buttons without adding any more html? I usually do the programming end of sites and not the javascript - jQuery is still new to me.

I know that:

```
var imageCount = jQuery('.gallery li').length;
```

will give me the number of images, but I'm lost on where to go from there.

**Edit:**

The output that I'm trying to achieve is something like:

```
<ul class="gallery">
    <li><img src="example-one.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="example-two.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="example-three.png" /></li>
</ul>
// Added with jQuery
<ul class="gallery-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Button One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Button Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Button Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Whereby the .gallery-nav would be used to navigate through the images (i.e. clicking 'Button Two' would display example-two.png)

Comment: which result you want to get in html?

Comment: sorry andres, I should have put that in there. I'll edit it right now.

Comment: you are just asking for clickable images?  Meaning, clicking example.png takes you to another page?

Comment: hey Marc, I did another edit to the post to hopefully convey what I'm going for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where would you like your buttons to go? If you want to do something for each of something of another thing, you can use jQuery's .each() method like this:

```
$('.gallery img').each(function() {
    alert("This is image " + $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

And here's an example of how to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/3HeFS/

Answer (score 3):

You mean this:

```
var imageCount = jQuery('.gallery li').length;

for(var i=0; i<imageCount; i++){
 $('button').appendTo($('body'));
}
```

You can replace the `$('body')` above to append the buttons elsewhere too since you have not mentioned where you want to place those buttons.

Answer (score 2):

```
var names = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
$('.gallery li').each(function(i, el) {

    var oldHtml = $(this).html();
    $(this).empty().html('<a href="#">Button '+names[i]+'</a>');


});​
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/44J93/)